# Wordpress password protected page not actually protected

Tags: php, wordpress, passwords, password-protection

I am having issues with a password protected page. I have set the visibility to password protected but when I access the page (logged out) from my usual browser (Chrome) as well as Firefox and IE11 I can still access the page, but the page title now says *PROTECTED: PAGE TITLE*.

In the [Using Password Protect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Password_Protection) codex entry it says *WordPress stores this password in a browser cookie so readers don't have to re-enter passwords if they visit the same page multiple times*. I am trying to have the page locked up completely so the user needs to enter a password every time they try and go to that page. All the google posts I find are geared towards password protecting posts and I can't find any plugins that will specifically do pages, they all say that WP has that built in, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I do not really know why you want to torment your already authenticated users , but you can do one of two things :

1 - set your own cookie .

```
function o99_set_newvisitor_cookie() {
    if ( !is_admin() && !isset($_COOKIE['sitename_newvisitor'])) {
        setcookie('sitename_newvisitor', 1, time()+3600*24*100, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false); // change time ...
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'o99_set_newvisitor_cookie');
```

and after that in your theme

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['sitename_newvisitor'])) {
     echo 'We need password'; 
}
else {
     echo 'we do not need password'; 
}
```

2 . reduce authentication sesssion length using the `auth_cookie_expiration` filter. ( following is just an example - change for own needs )

```
function o99_cookie_expiration( $expiration, $user_id, $remember ) {
    return $remember ? $expiration : 600;
}
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 'o99_cookie_expiration', 99, 3 );
```

Now depend on your time settings, this will kick the user out .

Other , not recommended options would be a JS overlay window, or `session` control with `php` .

But, like said before, I do not really know why you want to do that - I am pretty sure you do not really thought it through.

And last thing - have you checked your theme files to see that they really do conditionals for protected on all data ?

```
  if ( !post_password_required() ) {
    echo 'protected content'; //or content or title or whatever ..
  }
```

Comment: I'm not trying to password protect pages from logged in users; I want a password protected page for visitors, so when they go to it they simply need a password to view the page/content. No login/password, but a simple password.

Comment: First , you have to make your question more clear , second, the built in password protection does exactly what you are describing in comment - without login. third - please see the last part of my answer again. is your theme ready for password protection ??

Comment: The following suggestion by @ObmerkKronen does the trick to protect the content  if ( !post_password_required() ) {
    echo 'protected content'; //or content or title or whatever ..
  }